# Passing variable arguments with different types to method in java?

Tags: java

If you want to pass variable number of same type, we can use ... like

```
public boolean isEqual(String... arr)
```

Wondering how to pass variable number of different types?

What I want is: 
In caller, I have three different types: CustomClass, String, and Throwable.

```
void test() {
    CustomClass obj = new CustomClass("name", 12);
    caller("Hello", obj);
    caller("Hello");
    caller(obj, new Throwable("test"));
    // and more caller with different combination of arguments
}
```

What I can think of is Object,

```
public static boolean method(Object... arr)
```

For this purpose, we can use Builder pattern, but what if using Builder pattern is not easy for some reason, passing variable Object is the best or is there some other option?

Comment: What do you want `caller` to do with the arguments?  Does that behaviour depend on the types?

Comment: If you don't know the type of object `Object` is your only option.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.  What is it that you're actually trying to do here?  Why do you need a single method you can call so many different ways, instead of creating overloads with different signatures?

Comment: If you only want those 3 object types, and only zero or one of each, then the common way of doing that in Java is to create 7 (or fewer) **overloads** of the method *(assuming at least one is required)*. Usually, the overload taking all 3 is the only one doing the work, and the others call it with `null` values for the missing parameters.

Comment: The variables from a ... will result in an Array, if you want such you go with the Object approach, if you want to name each of those and expect a fixed number of variables you just declare then as arguments

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can **overload** your specific method to cover the different **Object** Types you want to deal with however, if (for whatever reason) you have a method where you would like an optional number of different Object Type arguments to be passed to it (***in any order***) then you can use **Object** as the argument type:

```
private void call(Object... object) {
   // Method code here.
}
```

and within the method use something like:

```
String objectType = object[indexNumber].getClass().getSimpleName();
```

to determine the type of Object that was supplied at any particular argument index.

Here is a quick example:

```
// Declare and initialize some variables...
byte byt = 12;
char chr = 65;
Point pnt = new Point(100, 200);
String[] array = {"hello", "world"};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Object obj = this;
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("hello");

// call our method supplying various values, variables, 
// and objects...
call('A', 32.657, 34, 21.3f, "Hello", 2147483647898L, 
        byt, chr, pnt, array, list, myLabel, obj, 
        new Throwable("test"));

/* Example Method Only! This method can accept no
 * arguments or optionally accept any number of 
 * arguments of any Object Type in any Type order.
 *
 * Displays to Console The Object Type supplied in each
 * supplied optional argument.
 * 
 * Returns: Nothing (void)
 */
private void call(Object... object) {
    Object returnObject;
    String msgAdd =  "- Do whatever in method to handle this argument.";

    if (object.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No Arguments supplied! - " +
                "Do whatever in method to handle this situation.");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        String objType = object[i].getClass().getSimpleName(); 
        System.out.println("Argumant supplied at Index " + i + " is a " + 
                objType + " Object!" + (objType.length() < 6 ? "\t\t" : "\t") + 
                msgAdd);
    }
}
```

If you run the above code you should get something like this displayed within the Console window:

```
Argumant supplied at Index 0 is a Character Object!   - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 1 is a Double Object!      - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 2 is a Integer Object!     - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 3 is a Float Object!       - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 4 is a String Object!      - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 5 is a Long Object!        - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 6 is a Byte Object!        - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 7 is a Character Object!   - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 8 is a Point Object!       - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 9 is a String[] Object!    - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 10 is a ArrayList Object!  - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 11 is a JLabel Object!     - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 12 is a MyClass Object!    - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
Argumant supplied at Index 13 is a Throwable Object!  - Do whatever in method to handle this argument.
```

Comment: thanks for double-check. I also thought the variable length of Object vars will be the one that I needed to use for this specific requirement where I can't use Builder pattern nor method overloading.